# how to remove duplicates php array_unique not working

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, array-unique

I try using `array_unique();` but not working this is my code please help me what i doing wrong? I want display all tags without duplicates

```
ID | TAGS
1 | rock, punk, jazz
2 | pop, rock, classic
3 | jazz, blues, rock
4 | rock, rap, metal

$wynik = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nabk_t_item_tags") or die('B&#322;&#261;d zapytania');
if (mysql_num_rows($wynik) > 0) {
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($wynik)) {
        $input = $r['tags'];
        $fields = explode(',', $input);
        $fields2 = array_unique($fields);
        foreach ($fields2 as $field) {
            echo '"' . $field . '",';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Start by showing us an example of what is contained in the `tags` column. Then describe what is wrong with your existing code that needs fixing

Comment: sorry please elaborate, what are you expecting and what is it doing?
You want to only receive one of each value?

Comment: I want display all tags without duplicates (rock, punk, jazz, pop, classic, metal etc.)

    ID | TAGS
    1 | rock, punk, jazz
    2 | pop, rock, classic
    3 | jazz, blues, rock
    4 | rock, rap, metal

Comment: You should add each tag in new row, not comma separated. Then things will get real easy. That table won't insert duplicates and you only have to do `select * from tags`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($wynik) > 0) {
    $used=array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($wynik)) {
        $input = $r['tags'];
        $fields = explode(',', $input);
        foreach($fields as $tg){
            if(!isset($used[$tg])){
                echo '"' . $tg . '",';
                $used[$tg]=" ";
            }   
        }
    }
    unset($used);
}
```

Comment: This solution working perfect. Thanks very much all for help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put all the tags from the query in one single array. So, using your existing code:

```
// $fields2 = array_unique($fields);
$fields2 = array_merge($fields2, $fields);
```

Then after the while loop, `$fields2` will have all the tags and you can array_unique that array. So, add these lines and see the result:

```
    } // end while
    $unique_tags = array_unique($fields2);
    var_dump($unique_tags);
} // end if
```

Comment: Your solution is good - for someone who worked with PHP (obviously he didn't), therefore he may not understand it. Edit your answer with a full working code and comments, and he might get it.

Comment: @besciualex thanks, edited to make it easier to understand